# Why is the present simple used?

Tags: grammar, present-tense, present-simple

I don't understand why the present simple tense is used in this sentence. Could anyone explain it for me?

[image]

Comment: We use Present Tense verb forms to refer to actions / states that ***were, are***, and ***will be*** happening. That's because Past Tense usually implies *not now, and not in the future*, and Future Tense implies *not in the past, and not yet now*, but Present Tense can imply ***always*** as well as ***at this current moment***. Note that ***dedicated*** is an ***adjectival*** usage in the cited context, not really a "past tense verb" usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the uses of the present simple is to express a fact, something which is always true. In this case it is used because that is what the Red Cross does, helping people in extremely difficult circumstances like war, natural disaster, etc. It is their "core business" so to speak.